# mysql_query results in a while loop X 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am completely stumped here, Thanks in advance for any solutions or pointers, I really do appreciate any help you can offer.

I am trying to make a memo system. Showing memo's is  no problem but I am trying to only show the unread memo's. I have 2 tables as you can see, one that has the memo's and the other that lists the read memo's.
when a user has read the memo's he/she ticks the box and the memo id  and the user id is added to the table 'memo_read'.

So basically I am trying to retrieve the memo's that have been read from the 'memo_read' table and then display the results from the 'memo' table that haven't been read where the user_id and the company are correct.
As you can see I have 2 variables from a function on another page and these are working fine '$user_id , $company_id',

I am trying to display the unread memo's in a while loop displaying the desired variables. I have been working on this for ages and no joy, I have tried every approach i can think of but i'm sure you can tell i'm not the most experienced of guys and i'm sure am have missed some thing or have taken the completely wrong approach!

```
<?php
$user_id = $user_data['user_id'] ;
$company_id = $user_data['company'];

$result1 = mysql_query ("SELECT `user`, `memo_id` FROM`memo_read` WHERE `user`= '$user_id '") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$memo_id   = $row['memo_id']; 


$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `link`, `author`, `time`, `title`, `company` FROM `memo` WHERE `worker`= 1 AND `company`= '$company_id' AND `id`!= '$memo_id'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    {

    $id           = $row['id']; 
    $link         = $row['link'];
    $author     = $row['author'];
    $time        = $row['time'];
    $title         = $row['title'];
    $company  = $row['company'];

?>

<ul>
    <li><?php  echo $title; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $author; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $company;?></li>
    <li><?php echo $time;?></li>
    <a href="<?php  echo $link; ?>"> Read memo</a> 
</ul><br>
<?php
}   }
?>
```

Comment: obligatory comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, please use `mysqli_*`.

Comment: You're running nested queries. With very few exceptions, it'd be better to re-write them as a single `JOIN`-ed query.

Comment: Also, check out `extract()`.

Comment: when i see a query in a loop created by another query - you know ethers a problem, one query with a join is what you need

Comment: Use `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), it's saves you some code. You can echo it like this: `<?php echo $row->id; ?>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
<?php
$user_id = $user_data['user_id'] ;
$company_id = $user_data['company'];

$result1 = mysql_query ("SELECT `user`, `memo_id` FROM`memo_read` WHERE `user`= '$user_id '") or die(mysql_error());
$memo_id_query = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$memo_id_query .= " AND `id`!= '".$row['memo_id']."'";
}


$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `link`, `author`, `time`, `title`, `company` FROM `memo` WHERE `worker`= 1 AND `company`= '$company_id' ".$memo_id_query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    {

    $id           = $row['id']; 
    $link         = $row['link'];
    $author     = $row['author'];
    $time        = $row['time'];
    $title         = $row['title'];
    $company  = $row['company'];

?>

<ul>
    <li><?php  echo $title; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $author; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $company;?></li>
    <li><?php echo $time;?></li>
    <a href="<?php  echo $link; ?>"> Read memo</a> 
</ul><br>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: While this might work it's still making numerous calls to the database when one properly structured query will do the whole job.

Comment: @MikeW - I think it's only 2 calls to the db. Is it write?

Comment: If there're a lot of read memos maybe it could result in a really huge query and overflow sql buffer? I'm not sure, but I guess there's a lenght limit for SQL sentences

Comment: @OscarPérez - everything is limited :) For MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html 
In this case, there should be no problems with the load database and buffer.

Comment: That's great, it works fine and I like and understand this answer, i'm sure i will use it over and over.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a query that returns unread memos?
Something like:

```
 SELECT `id`, 
        `link`, 
        `author`, 
        `time`, 
        `title`, 
        `company` 
   FROM `memo` 
  WHERE `worker`= 1 
    AND `company`= '$company_id' 
    AND `id` NOT IN (SELECT `memo_id` 
                       FROM `memo_read` 
                      WHERE `user`= '$user_id '
                    )
```

Comment: Probably. But I think the suquery makes it very clear to understand, isn't it?